# Questions about the hyperbolic system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

$$u_t+A(x,t,u)u_x=b(x,t,u) \tag 1$$
$$u=(u_1, \dots, u_n), b=(b_1, \dots, b_n)$$
$$A=[a_{ij}], i,j = 1, \dots, n$$
$$$$
We set the question if there are characteristic directions at the path of which the PDE system $(1)$ is reduced to an ODE system.

So we take linear combinations of the above equations.

We use the vector $$\gamma=(\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n). \tag 2$$

We take $$\gamma^T(u_t+Au_x)=\gamma^Tb. \tag 3 $$

We want to conclude to a form of total derivative of the linear combination of $u$.

That means:(we consider that $u_j=u_j(x(t),t)$)

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma_1u_1+\gamma_2u_2 +\dots+\gamma_n u_n)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\gamma_1u_1+\gamma_2u_2 +\dots+\gamma_n u_n)+\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\gamma_1u_1+\gamma_2u_2 +\dots+\gamma_n u_n)$$

and we define $\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda$

The relation above means:
$$m^T\left(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+\lambda\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\right)=\gamma^Tb \tag 4$$

From the relation $(3)$ and $(4)$, we see that $\gamma=m=(\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n)$ and that $\gamma^TA=\lambda \gamma^T$

$\lambda:$ eigenvalue of the matrix $A$

$\gamma^T:$ left eigenvector of $A$

$$$$
We define the characteristic directions:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda, \text{ so } \gamma^T(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{dx}{dt} 
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}})=\gamma^Tb$$

$$\gamma^T \frac{du}{dt}=\gamma^Tb$$

We conclude that to reduce the PDE system to an ODE system, the matrix $A$ should have $n$ discrete real eigenvalues.

In this case we say that the system is hyperbolic.
$$$$

---

- I haven't understood the relation $(4)$... Could you explain it to me?? What is $m$??

Answer (score 1):

Equation 4 is unusual - I believe that $m$ is just a stand in for an arbitrary left handed eigenvector and so the right hand side should be $m^Tb$

Usually I have seen this done where we explicitly know we are going after the left handed eigenvectors (for example - for Euler's equation from gas dynamics there are two eigenvalues and two eigenvectors). Exploiting the left handed eigenvectors $\underline{is}$ the big trick.

So, if I know that $E_i$ is the $ith$ left handed eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ then hitting $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + A\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = b$ on the left with $E_i$ yields $E_i^T(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \lambda_i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}) = E_i^Tb$.

Then we can define a new variable (the $ith$ Riemann invariant) $R_i$ such that $\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial t} + \lambda_i\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial x} = E_i^Tb$. Where $\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial t} = E_i^T\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$.

(We aren't always so lucky as to have $E_i$ be a bunch of constants - usually, they depend on the primitive variables of the system)

Now we define the characteristic curve by $\frac{dx}{dt} = \lambda_i$ and we can track the evolution of $R_i$ along the characteristic curves via $\frac{d R_i}{dt} =  E_i^Tb$

Comment: So, is $m$ the ith Riemann invariant $R_i$??

Comment: Not quite, equation 4 is valid if $m$ is one of the the right handed eigenvector of $A$, additionally - I think the right hand side has a typo - and should be $m^T\left(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+\lambda\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\right)=m^Tb$

Comment: Then the Riemann invariant $R_i$ is defined by $\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial t} = E_i^T \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. In the case of $E_i$ being a vector of constants you simply get $R_i = E_i^T u$, but in the case when $E_i$ depends on the primitive variables (contained in $u$) then it is more tricky.

Comment: For example the spherically symmetric case of Euler equations are $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\begin{pmatrix}\rho \\ z\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\f'(\rho)-\frac{z^2}{\rho^2} & \frac{2z}{\rho} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\rho \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2z}{r} \\ \frac{2z^2}{\rho r}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: this gives $\lambda_+ = \frac{z}{\rho} + \sqrt{f'(\rho)}$ and $\lambda_- = \frac{z}{\rho} - \sqrt{f'(\rho)}$. with left handed eigenvectors $E_+ = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{f'(\rho)}-\frac{z}{\rho}\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $E_- = \begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{f'(\rho)}-\frac{z}{\rho}\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $R_+ = \frac{z}{\rho} + G(\rho)$ and $R_- = \frac{z}{\rho} - G(\rho)$ where $G(\rho) = \int \frac{\sqrt(f'(\rho)}{\rho}d\rho$

Comment: Looks like I left the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ out of the Euler equation above (after the matrix).

Comment: on the first comment - I should have said $m$ is one of the 'left' handed eigenvectors